# Water coolso object by heat absorption

Tags: thermodynamics

Why do water of water based liquids like sweat cool objects? The most clear example I have is the sweat on the skin. I learned that it absorbed heat because it evaporates, but this is something strange. I also read that by putting a little water on a can under the sun will cool the inside of the can, for the same reason as sweat. Why is this?
Why does a liquid take away the heat, while it isn't even at the boiling point? The body is only 37 degrees Celcius, why does sweat "want" to evaporate already? I do know that liquids take energy to change its phase without adding to the temperature, but this is only at boiling point.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43327/

Answer (score 4):

Well you almost got it but then talked yourself out of it.  Yes it does take energy (latent heat) to convert a liquid (water) to a vapor .  That is the energy to overcome thing like Van der Waals forces that hold close packed molecules together and allow them to float free of such constraints.

But it is NOT true, that this only happens at the Boiling point.   It happens at any Temperature.   It takes approximately 593 calories per gram of water (at 100 deg C) to convert it into steam at 100 deg C.
At a lower Temperature, the water molecules will have less average kinetic energy, so it will take more energy to convert it to vapor at the lower Temperature, so the latent heat of evaporation will be somewhat higher than 593 calories per gram.
As a rough figure, you can assume one more calorie per gram for each degree lower Temperature.  So for ice water at near zero deg C it will take about 693 Calories per gram.

If the water is on your skin, that latent heat will be extracted from your warmer skin, which is why it makes you feel cooler.

The Temperature of a mass of material, reflects the average kinetic energy per molecule of the material.  But individual molecules have diffent energies which they exchange during their collisions.  Thes energies generally are distributed with some statistical distribution, often a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, which has a long high energy tail to it.  So there always are molecules with sufficient energy to escape the surface of the liquid, and fly free in the gaseous phase.   This lowers the average KE of the remainder , so it lowers the Temperature of the liquid.   But more high energy tail molecules will escape, anyhow, so evaporation can take place even well below the boiling point.  Of course if the atmosphere above the liquid should start to have more molecues of the liquid, (higher humidity for example), then some of those can collide with the liquid surface and be re-absorbed.   Evaporation will stop, when the number of higher energy molecules escaping, equals the number returning from the atmosphere above the liquid.

Hurricanes, which are powered by heat from warmer waters, suck a lot of latent heat of evaporation out of the ocean surface, so the hurricane leaves a cold surface water track behind it.

Comment: Great answer.  Another everyday example is the condensation or frost that often appears on BBQ propane tanks.  It takes heat to vaporize the propane, which it gets from the surroundings.  This cools the tank wall below the dew point, so water vapor in the air condenses on the tank.  Essentially, the latent heat in the water vapor is transferred to the propane vapor.

Comment: The latent heat phenomenon, also explains why steam is so extremely dangerous (specially for little kids in the kitchen.  If you heat water to almost 100 deg C, you wouldn't want to have some of that fall on your skin and deliver one calorie of heat energy for each degree it has to drop, before it reaches your body Temperature (37 deg C) so that's 63 calories for one gram of water dumped on your skin (1 cc)

Comment: Cut off too soon.   If the water boiled and became steam and one gram of steam came in contact with your skin, it would dump out 593 calories while it condenses, and then dump the 63 calories to cool down to 37 deg C, so that is 630 calories per gram of steam (at 100 deg C) instead of 63 Calories for one gram of 100 deg water; TEN TIMES AS MUCH HEAT ENERGY.

Comment: A very clear answer! But I still have my doubts: Why does a liquid take in heat? Is this because you said not all particles have the same energy, so always a part of a liquid will absorb the heat? I though only liquid cooler than 37 degrees can absorb heat, but since sweat is produced by yourself, it should be 37 degrees as well. How can this take in enough heat to evaporate? I understand that there will always be some particles that escape the liquid, but from 37 to 100 degrees is a lot.